# Connecting React and React Native with Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-native, mern

So I just started learning ReactJS and React Native.

I have some knowledge of MEN (Mongo, Express, Node). Up to this point, I learned how to res.render() files and pass objects in there.

Now what I need to do, is make MERN app. This app also needs to have Android and iOS version of it.

So far I learned that R stands for ReactJS, not react-native. Is there a way so it includes both? And where do I put react files when I have folder structure like from express-generator? Or is there a way they can be in completely different directories, and one calls the other via import?

Comment: Keep the server separate from the clients. The backend stack is irrelevant to your React front-end, and vice-versa. Your React apps should only know where the backend is, how to call it and what data to expect. The server shouldn't care who calls it as long as requests are well-formed and the origin is allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to architecture I believe.  The way I like to create the stack goes as follows.

You can create an API using Mongo/Express/Node that serves endpoints for your client app (created using reactjs, react-native and whatever other tech you want to include) to call using HTML requests.  This would work for both mobile apps (using react-native) and desktop apps (using reactjs).

There's a couple different ways to deploy this.  You can create 2 separate apps, a server app and a client app, which are both hosted individually by 2 separate hosts.  This is useful because you decouple your front end code from your back end code.  Also, you can have 2 separate directories for your code.

Another method of deployment would be to have your server serve your client files.  This ones a little bit tricker, but you will be able to deploy your entire app inside 1 host so this option is also cheaper.  I would suggest reading this article to figure out how to implement this and the file structure https://originmaster.com/running-create-react-app-and-express-crae-on-heroku-c39a39fe7851

Comment: I imagined doing it like you described in first place. Server serving APIs and separate it from front-end. My question is now, do I need to connect react-native and reactjs (because they will have very similar appearance), or I keep them separated, and treat them like 2 different projects in different directories? Do you maybe got some link or tutorial that could help me organize it this way?

Comment: Are you trying to target only mobile devices?  If so, use react-native.  If you're trying to make a hybrid app? Then use React and check out libraries like react-responsive.  Separate your server directory from your client directory and deploy them to 2 different hosts.